# Forwarding X through 2 servers (4 boxes involved)

Tags: ssh, xorg, openssh, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run a web browser on my desktop machine at work but display on my local laptop.

To connect via ssh, I need to go through 2 servers.

- A: Laptop wanting to display browser that runs on D.
- Server1
- Server2
- D: Desktop with browser installed

I've tried all sorts of combinations to get X forwarded through each host with no luck, X11Forwarding is enabled on all hosts and does work when the 2 servers are not involved.

Essentially, something like;

```
ssh -X user@server1 ssh -X user@server2 ssh -X user@desktop
```

Then I'd like to be able to launch applications on D but display on A.

when doing echo $DISPLAY on D, the display is not set, it seems to be 'lost' on server2.

```
Server1$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
Server1$ ssh -X user@server2

Server2$ echo $DISPLAY

Server2$
```

Many thanks

Comment: The ssh daemons on the relays are probably not configured for X11 forwarding.

Comment: All hosts are enabled for X11 forwarding whist attempting.

Comment: Did you check /etc/sshd_config for this? Also are all proxies configured for localhost display?

Comment: `X11Forwarding yes`
`AllowTCPForwarding yes`

Comment: I added some -v's and found out no xauth is on one of the proxies.

Comment: This surprises me a bit, since SSH is rolling it's own xauth implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xauth missing on proxy, discovered missing by adding -v to my ssh command.